# .NET Disposing DBContext on Controllers Dispose action

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I want to know if I am right doing this kind of job?

Here is a simple example.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    MYDBContext db = new MYDBContext();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //do some thing with db here
        return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

So, I'm creating a db object at the top of the controller. and disposing it when controller is disposing?

I'm wondering if there is a memory leak because of unclosed DB connections?

Edit : This is a MVC project.

Comment: Yes, there is a mistake. Google `Dependency Injection` and `IoC`.

Comment: As a rough concept it's OK. But you should not need or want this. IoC is built-in in Asp.Net Core, add a package for the regular MVC framework.

Comment: design perspective it is wrong coding

Comment: @programtreasures, I'm asking if there can be a memory leak because of not closed DB connections?

Comment: `db.Dispose();` would be slightly better as `db?.Dispose();` But @HenkHolterman is correct - this is the container's problem.

Answer (score 1):

**As far as db connection concern** .NET maintains a pool of connections for every connection string you use in your application, 
for perfomance reasons (because opening and closing connections often might be costly in terms of perfomance). 
That pool has certain minimum and maximum size (controlled by MinPoolSize and MaxPoolSize connection string parameters). 
When you open a connection (via SqlConnection.Open) - it might be taken out of the pool and not really opened afresh. 
When you close connection (which is also done by disposing EF context) - connection might be put into the pool instead, and not really closed. 
When connection is idle for certain time it might be removed from the pool.

Comment: All very true but not really addressing the question, is it?  Missing a Dispose() is still effectively a leak.

Comment: correct, I talk about db connection because OP has concern about db connection

Comment: so, what you think there may be a memory leak if I dispose all controllers like this, because of unclosed db connections?

Comment: @fobus of course it will dispose the dbcontext and db connection logically, but still connection will close considering `MaxPoolSize` param, the default value of `MaxPoolSize` is 100 and 'MinPoolSize' is 0, so if it is not set than it will close the db connection as well.